# Apache Reverse proxy - ProxyPass conflict over multiple location

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, httpd.conf

ProxyPreserveHost On

```
<Location /stores/identityiq>
    ProxyPass https://ncdlxxxasa0002:8443/identityiq
    ProxyPassReverse https://ncdlxxxasa0002:8443/identityiq
</Location>

<Location /identityiq>
    ProxyPass https://ncdlxxxasa0002:8443/identityiq
    ProxyPassReverse https://ncdlixxxsa0002:8443/identityiq
</Location>

<Location />
    ProxyPass https://ncdlxxxasa0002:8443/identityiq
    ProxyPassReverse https://ncdlxxxasa0002:8443/identityiq
</Location>
```

I have above three Proxypass based on the locations. The first condition "/stores/identityiq" gets output context as "/identityiq" which is configured as a source of the second Proxy pass. So, I am finally redirected to the ProxyPassReverse of the second condition not the first one.

My intention is

case1: If Location /stores/identityiq/foo
output must be /stores/identityiq/foo

case2: If Location /identityiq/foo
output must be /identityiq/foo